# VB.NET Mysql, should I use a MySQL Connector?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connector

I am making a program that is connecting to a MySQL database and I want to know if it is safe to use a MySQL Connector, I am going to be releasing it to the public but I dont want the database info to get leaked so I am going to obfuscate the code.

Is it safe?

thanks,
-adam

Answer (score 0):

No; that's not safe **at all**.

If you put your database credentials in the public, you will be attacked, no matter what you do with them.

Instead, you can:

- Not release the database credentials.
- Release the credentials of a user with no write access
- Use an access-controlled web service instead of accessing MySQL directly

Comment: Thanks for the answers, would you have any recommendations of how to make it 99.9% safe? Because I am trying to keep data and stuff like that, but I want to keep it secure.

Comment: It completely depends on what you're trying to do.  Obfuscation will not help at all.  You need to make sure that an attacker cannot do any harm with the information & credentials you release.

Comment: Would you suggest using something with PHP from an online webhost?

Comment: It completely depends on **what you're trying to do**.  What do you want to expose to the public, and how?